# error with nested route ( react-router )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an issue with setState().

**Here is my routes.tsx file**

```
export const Routes = (props:any) => (
<Router {...props}>
<Route path="/" component={Miramir}>
  <Route path="/profile">
    <IndexRoute component={Profile} />
    <Route path="/profile/update" component={ProfileUpdate} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

So, when i trying to use `/profile/update` route 
I have an warning and see that component which only for `/profile` route exists on `/profile/update`

***This is an error***

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the CountDown component.
```

***Component CountDown***

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    let timeLeft = this.secondsToTime(this.state.date);
    this.setState({time: timeLeft});
  }

_countDown = () => {
    this.setState({
      time: this.secondsToTime(this.state.date)
    })
  }
```

Calling `_countDown` every sec

Hope your help!

Thanks

Comment: I don'*t know if this solves your problem but nromally, paths are relative to the parent Route. so the route with path /profile/update is actually available at /profile/profile/update

Comment: Actually routes starting with / should be relative to the root, so my initial comment was wrong. But i always define my paths without starting / so they are relative and still work after changing a parent's path

Comment: Can you update the question to give more informations about your CountDown component? Where do you call setState()?

Comment: @MichaelRitter, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably call `_countDown()` via `setInterval()` I'd imagine. Did you clear that Interval in `componentWillUnmount()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can not call the *_countDown*  before the component mount (it means the component render method is already called and then you calling *_countDown* function).

calling _countDown inside setInterval may solve, but may fail again if you render method take more time than time provided in setInterval.

```
_countDown = () => {
    this.setState({
      time: this.secondsToTime(this.state.date)
    })
  }
```